# How can I make an item in a WHERE clause optional?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

```
public List<..> GetSomething(int column1Value, int column2Value, string column3Value)
{

 from t1 in this.DataContext.Table1
 where  t1.column1 == column1Value &&
    t1.column2 == column2Value &&
    t1.column3 == column3Value

}
```

Now I want to re-use the above query i.e. don't want to duplicate it, but the ONLY difference is I want the t1.column3 == column3Value to be option so I call this like:

```
GetSomething(1,2,"HELLO");
```

and

```
GetSomething(1,2);
```

Is it possible to make this part of the where clause conditional?  Meaning if you pass in "", then it ignores that clause?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, just break your statement into two parts like this:

```
var query = this.DataContext.Table1
                .Where( x => column1 == column1Value && x.column2 == column2Value);

if ( column3Value != "" )
    query = query.Where( x => x.column3 == column3Value);


// Your existing processing of query
```

Comment: Anyway the idea of using optional parameter should also be followed, because as what the OP posted, that's the only solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public List<..> GetSomething(int column1Value, int column2Value, string column3Value = null) {
  from t1 in this.DataContext.Table1
  where  t1.column1 == column1Value &&
         t1.column2 == column2Value &&
         (column3Value == null ? true :  t1.column3 == column3Value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest ou to define `OR operator` in order to define such as optional

Answer (score 0):

Make the parameter optional, and test for the lack of it:

```
public List<..> GetSomething(int column1Value, int column2Value, 
                                  string column3Value = null)
{

 from t1 in this.DataContext.Table1
 where  t1.column1 == column1Value &&
    t1.column2 == column2Value &&
    (column3Value == null || t1.column3 == column3Value)

}
```